# AJAX PHP Server side respond but I can not display the response in client side page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page to send some input data to a php page and the later should  resend the response and later some data from my server side should displayed on the client page.

I tracked the request and response is like this 6[{"Student_Id":"21","Student_Name":"Smith"}]

but I couldn't display the result in client side page

HTML Script

```
<input type="text" name="Roomnum" id="Roomnum">  </input>  
<select id="StudentsSelection" name="Student_Id" style="width:200px;height: 40px;"> 
  <option value="0">- Select -</option>
</select>
```

Ajax Script

```
 var Room_Id = $("#Roomnum").val();
 $.ajax({
 url: 'getStudents.php',
 type: 'post',
 data: {Room_Id:Room_Id},
 dataType: 'json',
 success:function(response){
 
 console.log("success");
 console.log(response);
 var len = response.length;
  $("#StudentsSelection").empty();
  for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
 var Student_Id = response[i]['Student_Id'];
 var Student_Name = response[i]['Student_Name'];
 $("#Roomnum").empty();
  $("#Roomnum").append(Student_Name);
  $('#StudentsSelection').append(`<option value="${Student_Id}"> 
  ${Student_Id}-${Student_Name}  
 </option>`); 
 }
    }  
        });
```

PHP script

```
<?php
include "database_connection.php";

 $Room_Id= $_POST['Room_Id'];
 echo $Room_Id;
 $stmt =  $connection->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE Room_Id =   '.$Room_Id.'   ");
 $students_arr = array();
 while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
    {
    $Student_Id = $row['Student_Id'];
    $Student_Name = $row['Student_Name'];
 
    $students_arr[] = array("Student_Id" => $Student_Id, "Student_Name" => $Student_Name);
}
  echo json_encode($students_arr);
 ?>
```

Comment: `$('#StudentsSelection').append(\` <option ` Is that backtick a typo?

Comment: Hi. what is `$("#Roomnum").append(Student_Name);` are you appending value in input-box ? Isn't that should be `.val(Student_Name)`

Comment: @Swati  .val(Student_Name) also doesn't work

Comment: Hi , check your browser console is there any error ?

Comment: @Michel no I mean that

Comment: @Swati no error

Comment: Remove this line `echo $Room_Id;` you are receiving `6`(normal text) as well with json data maybe that why its not working .Because i have already tested your code with json it works .

Comment: @Swati Removed success
degrees.php:112 Array(1)0: {Student_Id: "21", Student_Name: "SMITH"}length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
jquery.min.js:4 The specified value "SMITH" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.

Comment: @Swati Solved it now thank you

Comment: just comment this line `echo $Room_Id;` and check.

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the Ajax response to JSON before use it like a Json, I have try your code and it's just a string:

```
var Room_Id = $("#Roomnum").val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'getStudents.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {Room_Id:Room_Id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(response){
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        console.log("success");
        console.log(response);
        var len = response.length;
        $("#StudentsSelection").empty();
        for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
            var Student_Id = response[i]['Student_Id'];
            var Student_Name = response[i]['Student_Name'];
            $("#Roomnum").empty();
            $("#Roomnum").append(Student_Name);
            $('#StudentsSelection').append(`<option value="${Student_Id}">
              ${Student_Id}-${Student_Name}
             </option>`);
        }
    }
});
```

This should solve your problem about the response, but I don't know what are you trying to do about "Roomnum" input.

Comment: Sorry your code doesn't solve the problem                    Roomnum input doesn't matter,   $("#Roomnum").empty();
            $("#Roomnum").append(Student_Name);  just to check the respone